# delay the setInterval using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```js
 setInterval(function() {
   for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
     $('.cbx-fadeInLeft-' + i + '').toggleClass('active'); // this will run after every 5 seconds
   }
   //setTimeout(setInterval, 3000);
 }, 5000);
```

```css
.cbx-fadeInLeft-1.active {
  color: #3498db;
}
.cbx-fadeInRight-2.active {
  color: #3498db;
}
.cbx-fadeInLeft-3.active {
  color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style:none;color:white;font-size:22px;">
  <li style="margin: 0px 0 40px 0;"></li>
  <li class="cbx-fadeInLeft-1" style="margin: 0 0 18px 0;">XXX</li>
  <li class="cbx-fadeInLeft-2" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">YYY</li>
  <li class="cbx-fadeInLeft-3" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">ZZZ</li>
</ul>
```

In the above code i wanna to delay the code for some time n then start the for loop again..TO give the li in style..

I just Want one by one to highlight....

Comment: Put the code in a function instead of inline / use setTimeout to start it off / call the function from itself after your unspecified "delay".

Comment: Alternatively, in this case, put the `for` loop outside the interval and set the interval as `5000*i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the variable `i` outside the scope of `setInterval`, then to make it cyclic you just need to set the appropriate value.

```js
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  $('.cbx-fadeInLeft-' + i + '').toggleClass('active');
  i++;
  if (i == 4) {
    i = 1;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.cbx-fadeInLeft-1.active {
  color: #3498db;
}
.cbx-fadeInLeft-2.active {
  color: #3498db;
}
.cbx-fadeInLeft-3.active {
  color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style:none;color:white;font-size:22px;">
  <li style="margin: 0px 0 40px 0;"></li>
  <li class="cbx cbx-fadeInLeft-1" style="margin: 0 0 18px 0;">XXX</li>
  <li class="cbx cbx-fadeInLeft-2" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">YYY</li>
  <li class="cbx cbx-fadeInLeft-3" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">ZZZ</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: CAn we change the setInterval timing dynamically

Comment: @VinothNarayan, __No__ in that scenario you need to use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2):

Your code be like

```js
var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
   setActive();
   i++;
 }, 1000);


function setActive() {
  if (i >= $('li').length) {
    i = 1;
  }
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('.cbx-fadeInLeft-' + i).toggleClass('active');

}
```

```css
.cbx-fadeInLeft-1.active{ 
  color:#3498db;
 }

.cbx-fadeInLeft-2.active   
{
 color:#3498db;
}
.cbx-fadeInLeft-3.active
{
 color:#3498db;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style:none;color:white;font-size:22px;">
<li style="margin: 0px 0 40px 0;">   </li>
<li class="cbx-fadeInLeft-1" style="margin: 0 0 18px 0;">  XXX</li>
<li class="cbx-fadeInLeft-2" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;"> YYY </li>  
<li class="cbx-fadeInLeft-3" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">  ZZZ</li>
</ul>
```